# Android USB tethering bridging

Tags: android

I am using my android device to USB tether. However, its blocking bonjour services from my wireless printer. Is there any way to bridge the WiFi and the USB tethering on my android device so that my MBP is directly connected to my home LAN?

PS - I am fully **root** and **xposed** on Marshmallow